# How to split a String for every 3 occurrences of a character?

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I'm struggling to figure out how to split a text for every 3 occurrences of the "|" character. Here is my input:

```
123 | name1 | description | $ 2.980,00 | 234 | name2 | description | $ 2.980,00 | 345 | name3 | description | $ 2.980,00
```

This would be my desired output:

```
var array[0] = "123 | name1 | description | $ 2.980,00"
var array[1] = "234 | name2 | description | $ 2.980,00"
...
```

Comment: Does it have to be using regex?

Comment: I don't know, if there is another way to do it no problem :)

Comment: Better would be just [string.split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it this way (as Keng mentioned, it's called *tokenizing*):

```
var myarray=text.split("|");
var json = new Array();
for (var i=0; i+3<myarray.length; i+=4) {
 json.push({id: myarray[i], name: myarray[i+1],
         desc: myarray[i+2], price: myarray[i+3]});
}
```

Comment: Yeah, *tokenizing* the source is definitely the best route in my exp.

Comment: @thejh: It looks to me like [Javascript’s `text.split` function](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/kayseycarvey/jss4p1.html) only takes a string argument like `"|"`, not a regex argument like `/\s*\|\s*/`; is that right? I’m not saying there’s anything wrong with your answer, just trying to understand the library. Is there a version of `split` that takes a regex argument?

Comment: @tchrist: regexps also work, at least in Google Chrome: `"123a567b89h749".split(/[a-z]/g)` evaluates to `["123", "567", "89", "749"]`

Comment: @thejh: Then I am worried about passing `"|"`, since as a regex, it means something different than as a string.  **Oh wait!** Maybe it does something different with a string vs slashes??  I wonder then about variables passed into it instead.  Enquiring minds want to know! :)

Comment: @tchrist: Yes, the stuff inside slashes is a regex while the stuff inside quotes is a simple string.